# Issue with Prisma and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, prisma

So I am trying to add data to my database where there is a category linked to each part of a computer system. I'm getting a constant "Unique constraint failed on the constraint"
I'm unable to resolve the issue and came here.
My setup is right now with ExpressJS, MySQL, GraphQL. But right now I can't even enter the data.
I already was able to input the data for Category and it is not empty right now. But when trying to add the other data for the remaining connections. I'm getting an error.
Here is my schema.

```
        model Category {
      Tag_id          String      @id @default(uuid())
      Tag_description String
      Processor       Processor[] 
      Graphics        Graphics[]
      RAM             RAM[]
      Storage         Storage[]
    }
    
    model Processor {
      id    String   @id @default(uuid())
      name  String
      cost  Float    @db.Float
      Tags  Category @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [Tag_id])
      tagId String 
    }
    
    model Graphics {
      id     String   @id @default(uuid())
      name   String   @unique
      cost   Float    @db.Float
      tagsId String
      cat    Category @relation(fields: [tagsId], references: [Tag_id])
    }
    
    model RAM {
      id     String   @id @default(uuid())
      name   String   @unique
      cost   Float    @db.Float
      tagsId String
      Tags   Category @relation(fields: [tagsId], references: [Tag_id])
    }
    
    model Storage {
      id     String   @id @default(uuid())
      name   String   @unique
      cost   Float    @db.Float
      tagsId String   @unique
      Tag_id Category @relation(fields: [tagsId], references: [Tag_id])
    }
    
    model Users {
      id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
      email         String
      firstname     String
      lastname      String
      streetaddress String
      state         String
      zipcode       Int
      cellphone     String?
      password      String
      createdAt     DateTime @default(now())
      updatedAt     DateTime @updatedAt
      Cart          Cart[]
    }
    
    model Cart {
      Cart_id     String @id @default(uuid())
      OrderNumber String @unique
      UserId      Int
      user        Users  @relation(fields: [UserId], references: [id])
    }
```

After being able to add the data for Category. I started to add the data for Processor. But getting an error shown below. I know this error may end up hitting my other models that I have to add data to so hopefully knowing what the issue is going to resolve before hand.
This is the sample data I was inputting for the **Processor** model.

```
[
 {
    name: "Core i7 8 core 3.0 ghz",
    cost: 200,
    Tags: {
      connect: {
        Tag_id: "75a86dbc-0239-4344-9ae5-bfb49efda17b",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    name: "Core i9 10 core 2.7ghz",
    cost: 320,

    Tags: {
      connect: {
        Tag_id: "75a86dbc-0239-4344-9ae5-bfb49efda17b",
      },
    },
  },
]
```

but keep getting this error

```
Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `tagId_unique`
  at async main (/Users/syedkhurshid/Documents/Coding/FreshStart/LinuxIsBeautifulv2/backside/prisma/seed.js:133:17) {
  code: 'P2002',
  clientVersion: '2.30.3',
  meta: { target: 'tagId_unique' }
}
PrismaClientKnownRequestError3 [PrismaClientKnownRequestError]: 
Invalid `prisma.processor.create()` invocation:
```

I have no idea where this **tagId_unique** is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you already have records on the DB that conflict with the `tag_id` that you defined to be unique in your schema. Kindly double-check the value for the `tag_id`.